# Let $X$ be a metric space and let $A,B \subset X$. If $A \subset B$, prove that $int(A)\subset int(B)$ and $\bar{A} \subset \bar{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a metric space and let $A,B \subset X$. If $A \subset B$, prove that $int(A)\subset int(B)$ and $\bar{A} \subset \bar{B}$

**My attempt**

First, for $A \subset B \rightarrow int(A)\subset int(B)$

Let $x \in int(A)$, then $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subset  int(A)$. Besides, we know that $int(A) \subset A$ and $int(B) \subset B$ (Is it neccesary to prove that?) and $A \subset B$. So $B(x, \epsilon) \subset  int(B)$

Second, for $A \subset B \rightarrow \bar{A} \subset \bar{B}$

Let $x \in \bar{A}$, that is $x=\lim_{n \rightarrow ∞}x_{n}$ where $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in A. Then $x_{n} \in A$. We also know that $A \subset B$, so $x_{n} \in B$, that is $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in B, where $x=\lim_{n \rightarrow ∞}x_{n}$. Finally $x \in \bar{B}$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove this is using the following definitions of interior and closure :

- $\rm{int} A$ is the union of every open set included in $A$,
- $\overline A$ is the intersection of every closed set containing $A$.

If $U$ is an open set included in $A$, then $U\subset B$, so the union ${\rm int}A$ of those sets is included in $B$, and it is an open set, so it's included in ${\rm int}B$.

Now if $C$ is a closed set containing $B$, it contains $A$, so the intersection $\overline B$ of those sets is closed and contain $A$, so it contains $\overline A$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the definition for open ball requires only that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset A$, which justifies it also being a subset of $B$ and implies that $x$ is also an interior point of $B$.

Your second part is spot on.